# How can I use Angular to create interactive widgets from vanilla (non-Angular) HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an Angular application: a training engine which will present online courses to the user.

Each course is basically a series of "slides" - HTML partials which the user can navigate through in sequence. Each slide can include zero or more interactive widgets of varying types: simple quizzes, hands-on exercises, etc.

My goal is for the courses to consist of pure HTML/CSS, so that less technical folks can build courses without having to get their hands dirty with JS or Angular. That's fine as long as courses only contain static HTML. But it gets tricky when I want to add the interactive widgets to a course.

For example, a sample course "slide" might look like this:

```
<p>Here's some static content introducing the quiz.</p>

<div class="quiz">

    <ol class="questions" data-passing-score="50">
        <li>

            <p>What was Abraham Lincoln's last name?</p>

            <ul class="answers">
                <li>Smith</li>
                <li>Johnson</li>
                <li class="correct">Lincoln</li>
                <li>Liebowitz</li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>

            <p>What were George Washington's false teeth made of?</p>

            <ul class="answers">
                <li>Particle board</li>
                <li class="correct">Wood</li>
                <li>The bones of his enemies</li>
                <li>Advanced space-age polymers</li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ol>

</div>

<p>Here's some static content that appears after the quiz.</p>
```

...and, when this HTML file gets loaded (presumably via `$http.get()`), my application would notice that it contains a `div` with the class `quiz`, and would set up the needed interactivity: tweaking the structure of the markup (*e.g.*, adding radio buttons and a submit button), perhaps hiding and showing elements (so the user would only see one question at a time), scoring the quiz on submission, etc.

This is a pretty common pattern in jQuery-land. Of course, we're not *in* jQuery-land.

If I'm thinking about this correctly, there are two problems I would need to solve to make this work.

**Problem 1:** First, I would need to get the quiz data out of the raw HTML, and into a JavaScript object. For example, I might parse the HTML above into a structure like this:

```
var quiz = {
    passing_score: 50,
    questions: [
        {
            ask: "What was Abraham Lincoln's last name?",
            answers: [
                { text: "Smith", correct: false },
                { text: "Johnson", correct: false },
                { text: "Lincoln", correct: true },
                { text: "Liebowitz", correct: false }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
};
```

I guess I'd want to convert the loaded HTML into a DOM tree (just in memory, not appended to the document), and then explore it (using jQuery or jqLite) to find the data I'm interested in.

**Is that a sensible approach? Are there other approaches I might want to explore?**

**Problem 2:** Second, I would need to *replace* `div.quiz` in the loaded HTML with the contents of a quiz template, like this:

```
<form ng-controller="QuizController as quizCtrl" ng-submit="quizCtrl.submit()">

    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="question in quizCtrl.questions">
            <p ng-bind-html="question.ask"></p>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="{{ 'q' + $parent.$index }}" ng-model="question.selected_answer" ng-value="answer">
                        <span ng-bind-html="answer.text"></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>

    <button type="submit">Score Quiz</button>

</form>
```

...and bind that div to QuizController.

**How do I dynamically bind a particular DOM node to a particular controller? How do I get the quiz object (which I constructed in the previous step) *into* the controller's scope?**

**Is there a standard-ish solution to this problem in Angular-land? Or is this entire approach just totally bananas?**

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: My first instinct is that if your reasoning to make vanilla HTML is only to convert it into another template for simplicity's sake, why not START with JSON? Have people write quizzes like your snippet under problem 1, fetch that stuff in your controller, you could even have only one controller

Comment: sounds like directives to me...

Comment: @azium: That's a good point, and I thought of that myself. However, that just creates new problems: how do quiz authors declare *where* in the HTML file that quiz should be rendered? Now quiz authors need to know HTML *and* JSON, have to juggle multiple files for a single slide, and need to deal with weird non-standard HTML tags or attributes (because they'd presumably need to use something like that to indicate where the JSON-defined quiz should be inserted into the markup, and *which* quiz JSON should be rendered there).

Comment: One possibility is to use a task runner (such as Grunt) to *compile* the plain HTML/CSS course into a JSON file. That's not a terrible option - but I'm still curious to know how it might be possible to do it the way I originally described.

Comment: Well obviously you, as the developer, would have to handle that, but a very simple directive would work. something like `<div quizzify="historytest.json"></div>` Where quizzify is a directive that fetches the json contents and populates your quiz.

Comment: Good idea! I'll definitely keep that option in mind.

Comment: you can rephrase the question to 'how do i change the controller..' then you could take a dom element with a controller and in that controller - get the quiz data (eg comments by @azium) and then use `$controller` service to change the controller of  the right kind

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as @dandavis suggested in the comments above, is [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

For my quiz example, I could create a custom directive that defines a custom  element. (Alternately, I could use `restrict: 'C'` in my directive definition to match `<div class="quiz">`, or `restrict: 'A'` to match on `<div quiz>`.)

Then, I just would put all my setup-and-DOM-massaging logic in the directive's link function.

Finally, I would just need to specify to the course authors how they should mark up a quiz.

I haven't fully played this out in real code yet, but I'm pretty sure this is all accurate.